# PHP: How can I determine if a variable has a value that is between two distinct constant values?

Tags: php, if-statement, intervals, between

How can I determine using PHP code that, for example, I have a variable that has a value

- between 1 and 10, or
- between 20 and 40?

Comment: No, I don't get the idea!  You mean "pick a random number between 1 and 10"?  Or "calculate the value half-way between 1 and 10"?  Or something else?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do want to *get* a random value between 1 to 10 or 20 to 40 or do you want to *test* whether some value is in these ranges? Or even something else?

Comment: I know, PHP could really do with the SQL equivalent of the BETWEEN statement.  It's not hard to do a if(x>=1 && x<=10), but somehow a between might be neater.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

```
if (($value > 1 && $value < 10) || ($value > 20 && $value < 40))
```

Comment: Leaves out the fact that the number could be 1 or 10, 20 or 40.

Comment: @VikingBlooded got to love the ambiguity of English and off by one errors

Comment: there is no helper function to check a number between 2 numbers in PHP?

Answer (score 22):

Do you mean like:

```
$val1 = rand( 1, 10 ); // gives one integer between 1 and 10
$val2 = rand( 20, 40 ) ; // gives one integer between 20 and 40
```

or perhaps:

```
$range = range( 1, 10 ); // gives array( 1, 2, ..., 10 );
$range2 = range( 20, 40 ); // gives array( 20, 21, ..., 40 );
```

or maybe:

```
$truth1 = $val >= 1 && $val <= 10; // true if 1 <= x <= 10
$truth2 = $val >= 20 && $val <= 40; // true if 20 <= x <= 40
```

suppose you wanted:

```
$in_range = ( $val > 1 && $val < 10 ) || ( $val > 20 && $val < 40 ); // true if 1 < x < 10 OR 20 < x < 40
```

Answer (score 10):

You can do this:

```
if(in_array($value, range(1, 10)) || in_array($value, range(20, 40))) {
   # enter code here
}
```

Comment: This looks very clean but be aware that i.e. testing for a price being between one and million means creating an array with million items. I've just measured both ways with microtime() and this one seems to run around 2000x slower for such large range while also consuming a lot of memory.

Comment: the solution `looks wonderful`, `works Awful`

Answer (score 7):

```
if (($value >= 1 && $value <= 10) || ($value >= 20 && $value <= 40)) {
   // A value between 1 to 10, or 20 to 40.
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Sorry for the late answer, but this function allow  you to do that.

```php
  function int_between($value, $start, $end) {
    return in_array($value, range($start, $end));
  }

  // Example
  $value1 = 20;
  $value2 = 40;
  echo int_between(20, $value1, $value2) ? "true" : "false";
```

Answer (score 4):

Guessing from the tag 'operand' you want to check a value?

```
$myValue = 5;
$minValue = 1;
$maxValue = 10;

if ($myValue >= $minValue && $myValue <= $maxValue) { 
  //do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a good solution.

```php
function int_between($value, $min, $max) {
    return in_array($value, range($min, $max));
}
```

I think this one is faster than the above

```php
function int_between2($value, $min, $max) {
    return $value == min($max, max($min, $value));
}
```

But, this is 3 times faster than others.

```php
function int_between3($value, $min, $max) {
    return ($value >= $min && $value <= $max);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to check the value is in Range, use this:

```
   MIN_VALUE = 1;
   MAX_VALUE = 100;
   $customValue = min(MAX_VALUE,max(MIN_VALUE,$customValue)));
```

Comment: This doesn´t check the value is between the range, it returns a new value that will be between the range.

Comment: Must be explained, given custom value, will return custom value itself if in range

Answer (score 0):

**Try This**

```
if (($val >= 1 && $val <= 10) || ($val >= 20 && $val <= 40))

This will return the value between 1 to 10 & 20 to 40.
```

Comment: Leaves out the fact that the number could be 1 or 10, 20 or 40.